# CF Builder Debugging config

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusionbuilder

G'day
For security reasons, our CFAdmin (and accordingly RDS) is accessed via one domain, say cfadmin.ourdomain.com, and access the site via a different domain: www.ourdomain.com.

Via some miracle I have just been able to get both RDS and a server set up without RDS giving me "Could not initialize class com.adobe.rds.core.services.Messages" (this is a first), and will allow me to launch a debugging session.  However it tries to hit the file I'm testing via cfadmin.ourdomain.com (and the actual website is not defined on that IIS website).  I can understand why this happens, but I can't figure out how to tell the debugging config that the actual website is www.ourdomain.com.

It is not a possibility to have either CFIDE accessible on www.ourdomain.com, or the site accessible via cfadmin.ourdomain.com.  So that cannot be part of a proposed solution.

Anyone have any ideas?

Oh: this is on CF9.0.1.

UPDATE:
Sorry, just to be absolutely clear... this is our *dev* environment. This is all running on my local PC. However the local server (a VM running on my workstation) is configured the same as the prod environment (for obvious reasons), down to how CFAdmin is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you will like :)  Your security folks were right in the first place. CF Builder debugging is a development tool designed to be used on a dev system and it works well mostly in a *local dev environment* where CF+ Apache or IIS are running on your local workstation.

On a production server RDS itself is a weakness that you really don't want running in that production environment (sorry). Having said that here are my big ideas :)

- Have your admin create a folder on cfadmin.ourdomain.com that points to your prod code. Depending on your code you might get that to work.
- Point cfadmin.ourdomain.com to your production code directly (no folder). After all the CFIDE and other mappings used by RDS are aliases or virtuals anyway.

That's all I got sorry....

Comment: Sorry, just to be absolutely clear... this *is* our dev environment.  This is all running on my local PC.  However the local server (a VM running on my workstation) is configured the same as the prod environment (for obvious reasons), down to how CFAdmin is accessed.  And - as per my initial post - making changes to the website configuration to accommodate CFB is not an option.

The domain name one accesses the site upon should not be so intriniscally bound to the domain name RDS comms run on, surely?  It's all the same CF server.

Cheers for your feedback though, Mark.  Much appreciated.

Comment: cool.. sorry to be pedantic and unhelpful (ha).  I can't think of a way around it...

Comment: Nono, I think it was very good advice to suggest, based on the info I had given you @ the time. Cheers.